# SharePoint 2010 Form Integration with iPad App

Tags: database

This might be an odd question and honestly I don't know if it is possible or not.  I have a client that is wanting an iPad App form which we developed to be synced/integrated with a SharePoint 2010 form library version of it.  Basically when the form is submitted on the iPad it creates an item in the SharePoint Form Library and if you want to lookup a form submitted within SharePoint you can on the iPad.

I have looked through the External List route using a SQL Database as the middle man, but the limitations of not being able to use workflows or export to Excel are not acceptable in this request.

Is SharePoint 2010 capable of having data submitted directly to it's database from an iPad app and also able to send data back to the iPad app for read/write?  If so can you point me in the direct I would need to start looking into or the best approach to complete this?

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions anyone might be able to provide!

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use [SharePoint Web Services' Lists class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvclists.lists%28v=office.14%29.aspx)  to interact directly with your lists. It has methods to create and read items from lists in SharePoint.